# Is fulltext search enabled on Google App Engine Java platform?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

Seems only available in Django?

But the info is not the latest

Comment: See this thread:  http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/5936ff05df7f32dd/84d31c2bc7a4e928?show_docid=84d31c2bc7a4e928

Comment: So need to implement it by ourselves?It's nontrivial IMO..

Answer (score 1):

You can implement full text search using the Compass Indexing Engine See the following URL for further help http://www.kimchy.org/searchable-google-appengine-with-compass/

Comment: I doubt that this solution is scalable for any real-world use.